# Interaction between liquid mercury and magnetic fields

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-circuits

I came across the following experimental setup:

[image]

According to the answers I’ve been given, when the current flows through the circuit, the wire will jump up and down in the mercury.

How does the current through the mercury cause the wire to jump up and down?

I’ve searched online but all I can find is mercury beginning to spin when a current is applied, so please enlighten me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing special about using mercury. It is a conductor. You could use a copper sheet instead.

The apparatus starts with the wire in the mercury. The mercury conducts, so the circuit is complete. When current flows in the electromagnets above the mercury, they are magnetized and attract each other. This pulls the bottom electromagnet up.

The wire comes out of the mercury, breaking the circuit. This turns off the electromagnets. The bottom elecromagnet falls. The wire touches the mercury again.